# Get items from Listbox and put it into columns

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

i want to get the selected items from a multiselection listbox and put These items in the column below. i have already found out how  get the selected items but not how i can put These into a sheet.

heres a code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

      Dim Msg As String
      Dim i As Integer
      Dim reihe As Integer
      Dim spalte As Variant
      reihe = 30
      spalte = "A"

      For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
          If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
              Msg = Msg & ListBox1.List(i) & vbNewLine
          End If
      Next i

      MsgBox Msg


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say we want to put the values into column **B** starting at row 13.  After your *MsgBox*, include:

```
ary = Split(Msg, vbCrLf)
J = 13
For Each a In ary
    Cells(J, "B").Value = a
    J = J + 1
Next a
```

**EDIT#1:**

To start at the same point, but fill across, use:

```
ary = Split(Msg, vbCrLf)
J = 13
K = 2
For Each a In ary
    Cells(J, K).Value = a
    K = K + 1
Next a
```

Comment: thats cool! But is there an alternative to bring the selected items to the columns side by side? For example: B13,B14 and so on..

Comment: @ManInTheMiddle  I don't understand **side by side**

Comment: my mistake, sorry. i mean if i use your code the output will be in cell b13, b14. You iterate "J", but what if i want this in b13, c13, d13 (side by side)?! How can i iterate a letter like "B" into "c"